# NServicebus with NLog

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog, nservicebus

I'm trying to figure out how to configure my asp.net core app, that already works with NLog, so that NServiceBus will use it for its internal logging.  The current NLog config works perfectly.

NServiceBus refers to this, but I haven't found it helpful.

https://docs.particular.net/samples/logging/extensions-logging/

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {

        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseNServiceBus(hostBuilderContext =>
            {
                var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("MySite");
                endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();
                var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>();
                transport.ConnectionString(
                    "");

                var persistence =
                    endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<AzureStoragePersistence, StorageType.Sagas>();
                persistence.ConnectionString(
                    "");
                persistence.CreateSchema(true);

                //endpointConfiguration.SendOnly();
                endpointConfiguration.EnableUniformSession();
                persistence.AssumeSecondaryIndicesExist();
                return endpointConfiguration;
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.ConfigureLogging(x =>
                {
                    x.ClearProviders();
                    x.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
                });
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseNLog();
            });
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to [`NServiceBus.Extensions.Hosting` `1.1.0`](https://discuss.particular.net/t/nservicebus-extensions-hosting-1-1-0-minor-release-available/2031) which brings in built-in support for `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`. As long as the logging is configured before `UseNServiceBus` (order is important on the generic host)

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do this:

```
return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>())
    .ConfigureLogging(x =>
    {
        x.ClearProviders();
        x.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
    })
    .UseNServiceBus(hostBuilderContext =>
        {
            var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("MySite");
            endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();
            var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>();
            transport.ConnectionString(
                "");

            var persistence =
                endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<AzureStoragePersistence, StorageType.Sagas>();
            persistence.ConnectionString(
                "");
            persistence.CreateSchema(true);

            //endpointConfiguration.SendOnly();
            endpointConfiguration.EnableUniformSession();
            persistence.AssumeSecondaryIndicesExist();
            return endpointConfiguration;
        })
    .UseNLog();
```